# angularjs function accessible in whole app

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

now I have some experience dealing with angularjs I wonder often how to having **global functions** (commonly used in many controllers) accessibles in the  whole app.
my problem is *$scope* is only accesible  in its controller, I can imagine a solution adding these functions to *$rootScope*, but for now I only have added variables to *$rootScope*, I don't know how to add functions and, specially, where do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service which is injected into any controller that requires the function as already mentioned. However, if you prefer to define the function on the `$rootScope`, you can do something like this:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.add = function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
});
```

Then you can simple use this function in a controller as

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.mySum = $scope.add(5, 7);
});
```

Here is a working fiddle [Function in $rootScope](http://jsfiddle.net/ranru/vELvz/)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using it on the controller, seems a candidate for a [Service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services). Once defined, you can use dependency injection to use it in your controller.

This is the simplest snippet on using a service, but there are other ways of defining them. They are very well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//define service
myApp.service('helloWorld', function() {
    this.sayHello = function() {
        return "Hello World!"
    };
});

//inject the service
function MyCtrl($scope, helloWorld) {
    alert(helloWorld.sayHello());
}
```

Comment: my question was initially intended for using it on the controller. can you provide an example of globally available function into a Service, like lets say ... `check_email_format()` or   `select_menu(item)` ?

Comment: You can apply a method to the `$scope` or `$rootScope` as these are essentially objects, therefore you can assign a method like so: `$scope.foo = function() { console.log('bar'); };`. This will be available in all controllers that are children to the controller's scope you assign this method to.